# Avalonia : Have the size of a grid row resize depending on if the other rows are visible or not

Tags: grid, avalonia

I have a grid with three (3) rows and depending on a toggle buttons value, I want the two (2) last rows to be NOT visible (I set the content of these two (2) rows to : IsVisible="{Binding #ToggleButton.IsChecked}) and the content of row zero (0) to be stretched over the whole grid.

Since my content of the first row is set to VerticalAlignment="Stretch", I had expected that when the content of the two other rows was set to 'invisible', the content of my first row would automatically be adjusted to the full hight of the grid.

I have tried all possible values for the row definitions, but never with the expected result.

Code below :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition /> <!-- Upper panel -->
    <RowDefinition Height="5"/> <!-- Splitter -->
    <RowDefinition /> <!-- Lower panel -->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-- Upper panel -->
<Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Source="../Assets/Image01.png"/>
</Grid>
<!-- Splitter -->
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
    IsVisible="{Binding #ToggleButton.IsChecked}"/>
<!-- Lower panel -->
<Grid Grid.Row="2" 
    IsVisible="{Binding #ToggleButton.IsChecked}"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Source="../Assets/Image02.png"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I did not find a way to do it in the XAML only.

Therefore, for others having the same problem, I solved it like this :

Giving the Grid a name ('grGrid') so I can access the row definitions via code.

Setting the RowDefinition for the Lower Panel of my original code like this :

```
<RowDefinition Height="0"/> <!-- Lower panel -->
```

In the XAML and code behind adding a 'Click' event for the ToggleButton like this :

```
private void TbToggleButton_OnClick(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_tbToggleButton.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[0].MinHeight = 150;
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[2].MinHeight = 150;
    }
    else
    {
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[0] = new RowDefinition();
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[2].MinHeight = 0;
        _grGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);
    }
}
```

This works just fine.

If you want the splitter to be saved (and loaded on restart) (I do not need that in this case), I suggest looking at the solution bellow (it is for WPF, but should be simple to adapt for Avalonia).

[WPF GridSplitter - saving and restoring location AND splitting proportionately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018544/wpf-gridsplitter-saving-and-restoring-location-and-splitting-proportionately)